# iterating and outputting nested obj properties to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How I am supposed to call them if `item.NestObj.textpropertyVal` is incorrect?

```
success: function(data){

                var html = "";
                $.each(data.mainOutterObj, function (index, item) {
                    html += "<ul>";
                    console.log(item);
                    //$.each(item.data, function (index1, item1) {
                        html += "<li class='id'>" + item.id + "</li>";
                        html += "<li class='title'>" + item.title + "</li>";
                        html += "<li class='cast'>" + item.cast.name + "</li>";                                                                                                                                                         
                        html += "<li class='genre'>" + item.genre.type + "</li>";                                                                                                                                   

                    //});
                    html += "</ul>";
                });
```

As soon as I start trying to access the inner or nested object properties, they report `undefined`. For example, below 2 fail. (output as just `[object Object]`) or undefined. Presumably because I'm not accessing it the right way. Basically cast and genre are nested objects within `.mainOutterObj`, with the property values I want on them with field such as `.name` and `.type`.

```
html += "<li class='cast'>" + item.cast.name + "</li>";                                                                                                                                                         
html += "<li class='genre'>" + item.genre.type + "</li>";
```

How do I iterate and output these, the same way as the outer obj property values?

For example here is the response for nested cast object, you'll notice .`name` is present. But when the `item.cast.name` is written as above, it reports undefined.

[image]

Comment: what is your JSON value??

Comment: Did you console the JSON data and what error are you getting?

Comment: What result are you getting on `console.log(item);`?

Comment: Without an example of your JSON file then it is all guess work at to why your code isn't working.

Comment: Your `cast` is an array. Try `item.cast[0].name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cast` is an array with one element. You should:

```
html += "<li class='cast'>" + item.cast[0].name + "</li>";                                                                                                                                                         
html += "<li class='genre'>" + item.genre[0].type + "</li>";
```

You have to access the first element of `cast` (element 0) before you can get the property `name`

Answer (score 0):

Take the following statement:

```
html += "<li class='cast'>" + item.cast.name + "</li>";
```

Now if the value of the `html` is `undefined`, this means there is no property called `name` in the `item.cast` object.

If the value is `[Object Object]`, this means `item.cast.name` is an object rather than being a sting or a numeric value.